# How to get a .txt File into a jar and read it

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to get a .txt file into a jar.

I tried to put it in to the package i'm using.

This will lead to the result, that i can't use the following code:

```
 double[] test1 = ReadFile.readfile("Daten8B.txt");
```

Is there an other way to generate a jar with the .txt in it?

If not, how do i get the path of the .txt?

note:

to get the path i tried:

```
String pattern = "Daten8B.txt";
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:" + pattern);
```

the output here was:

> sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem$2@15db9742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `getResourceAsStream("/a.txt")` method to get your file.
An example would look like

`InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/Daten8B.txt");`

Your txt file should be in your source folder for this example.

Instead of Main you can use any class in your jar-file.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your text file into the resource directory. Then you can access it with:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Daten8B.txt");
```